# CUDA error: out of mem aloc result line 855. Does anyone experience the same issue?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Hey guys i recently bought a razer laptop with rtx 2080 to improve my renders. But everytime i start rendering i get this error. CUDA error: out of mem aloc result line 855. Does anyone experience the same issue ?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try rendering using CPU.. because I guess the 8GBs of GPU memory can't handle 13GBs of your scene memory. I've faced with with 4GBs of card and now I only use GPU for testing the scene in realtime live preview and always render with CPU.

when using GPU, Blender push the whole scene to GPU's memory and then CUDAs start rendering the image. while using CPU, the core starts rendering using CPU's core and threads.

**Edited**

Secondly you should try to lower down the memory load on GPU... 8GB is good memory for an average scene. There are many ways to reduce the momory in scene i.e.

1. if you are using HDRI.. user a step lower in size i.e (if you are using HDRI of 8K, try to use 4k or 2k and see what effects.
2. If you are using large textures, try to lower down their resolutions too.

You can also try with out all of the textures and see if it renders so quick then start enabling a few and then a few and then a few and each time render the scene with GPU.

And Last but not lease... try rendering the scene in lower resolution like.. instead of 4k of resolution try rendering in 50% or 25% in scale percentage.

[image: mm]

If you are still unable to render this.. then as blender says..

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: Is there a way to fix this problem? so that i can use the expensive rtx 2080 to render my images?

Comment: Thank @MartynasŽiemys .. I have edited the answer. and yes Pieter-Jan, see the answer edited above.

Comment: Thanks the hdri of 16k might've been a little too ambitious...  Can this issue be solved by buying extra RAM GB for my razer laptop?

Comment: NO, it will never. I owned a 32GB of system with 4GBs of GPU and system's ram can never be shared with GPU.  but yes.. you can render in passes... if this is an animation (use 2K HDRI and environment light) and render, and then render only HDRI without anything in the scene. and later combine them both.